# How does setPublicChainlinkToken work, what if this function does not sense the current chain environment?

Tags: chainlink

As we know, within ChainlinkClient.sol, there is a function: `setPublicChainlinkToken`, it would sense current chainlink info and set up the LINK token for `transferAndCall`, but when we enter into a totally new chain, how do we deal with such a situation?

Answer (score 1):

It works to use `setChainlinkToken(official LINK token address)` instead of `setPublicChainlinkToken()` for other chains. In order to make use of the `transferAndCall` function it must be a token following the ERC677 standard, you can find all official LINK token addresses here:
https://docs.chain.link/docs/link-token-contracts/#config